# Box2d revolute join in LimeJS

Tags: box2d, limejs

Sorry for this noobish question, I am new to LimeJS/Box2d.

I am trying to construct a BOX2d Revolute joint in LimeJS. Can someone provide me with a simple example illustrating the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the box2d demo (at lime/demos/tests/box2d_2.js) and use this function to create a revolute joint between 2 bodies.

```
function createRevoluteJoint(body1, body2, anchorPoint, box2dWorld){
    var revoluteJointDef = new box2d.RevoluteJointDef(false);
    revoluteJointDef.body1 = body1;
    revoluteJointDef.body2 = body2;
    revoluteJointDef.anchorPoint = anchorPoint;

    var joint = box2dWorld.CreateJoint(revoluteJointDef);
    return joint;
}
```